# JSON.parse resulting Unexpected Token error message

Tags: javascript, json

Sorry this question might be asked hundreds time, I looked for similar questions but I can not find a clue why I still receive this error.

When I try to parse this specific string below, it says "Syntax error: Unexpected token". This is JS code:

```js
var a = "[{&quot;ltd&quot;:&quot;40.88393692299686&quot;,&quot;lng&quot;:&quot;29.40516471862793&quot;,&quot;country&quot;:&quot;T&#252;rkiye&quot;,&quot;city&quot;:&quot;İstanbul&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;Tepe&#246;ren Mh., 2. Caddesi, 41480 Istanbul-Istanbul Province, Turkey&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Indoor Life Facory&quot;,&quot;detail&quot;:&quot;İTOSB 2.Cad. No.7 Tuzla / istanbul / Turkey&quot;,&quot;addressTypeId&quot;:1,&quot;adressType&quot;:&quot;&#220;retim Birimi&quot;},{&quot;ltd&quot;:&quot;40.97575903170847&quot;,&quot;lng&quot;:&quot;29.051960706710815&quot;,&quot;country&quot;:&quot;T&#252;rkiye&quot;,&quot;city&quot;:&quot;İstanbul&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;Fenerbah&#231;e Mh., Bağdat Avenue 184-190, 34724 Kadık&#246;y-Istanbul Province, Turkey&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Indoor Life Head Office&quot;,&quot;detail&quot;:&quot;Bağdat Cad. Heper Apt. \r\nNo:165/5 34730 \r\nSelami&#231;eşme / Kadık&#246;y / İstanbul / Turkey&quot;,&quot;addressTypeId&quot;:2,&quot;adressType&quot;:&quot;İdari Birim&quot;}]";
a = a.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
var jsonList = JSON.parse(a);
```

Comment: you need to replace `/r/n` using regex and then do JSON.parse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have `;BağdatCad.HeperApt.\r\n` in string, that was causing error , it was showing invalid `JSON`. You need to replace them with space or blank string using regex. So Correct code would be.

```js
var a = "[{&quot;ltd&quot;:&quot;40.88393692299686&quot;,&quot;lng&quot;:&quot;29.40516471862793&quot;,&quot;country&quot;:&quot;T&#252;rkiye&quot;,&quot;city&quot;:&quot;İstanbul&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;Tepe&#246;ren Mh., 2. Caddesi, 41480 Istanbul-Istanbul Province, Turkey&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Indoor Life Facory&quot;,&quot;detail&quot;:&quot;İTOSB 2.Cad. No.7 Tuzla / istanbul / Turkey&quot;,&quot;addressTypeId&quot;:1,&quot;adressType&quot;:&quot;&#220;retim Birimi&quot;},{&quot;ltd&quot;:&quot;40.97575903170847&quot;,&quot;lng&quot;:&quot;29.051960706710815&quot;,&quot;country&quot;:&quot;T&#252;rkiye&quot;,&quot;city&quot;:&quot;İstanbul&quot;,&quot;address&quot;:&quot;Fenerbah&#231;e Mh., Bağdat Avenue 184-190, 34724 Kadık&#246;y-Istanbul Province, Turkey&quot;,&quot;title&quot;:&quot;Indoor Life Head Office&quot;,&quot;detail&quot;:&quot;Bağdat Cad. Heper Apt. \r\nNo:165/5 34730 \r\nSelami&#231;eşme / Kadık&#246;y / İstanbul / Turkey&quot;,&quot;addressTypeId&quot;:2,&quot;adressType&quot;:&quot;İdari Birim&quot;}]";
a = a.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
a = a.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '');
console.log(a);
var jsonList = JSON.parse(a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your json is not valid ([jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com)).

you need to replace the new lines with `\\n` too.

```
// additional replace func call
a = a.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '\\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your text has new lines in it: `Apt. \r\nNo:165/`. (Note, they will be converted to actual new lines with the JavaScript parser parses the JavaScript source code into the string).

These are not allowed in JSON strings and must be replaced by escape sequences.